# Multi specific indexes vs. one general index with multi-filtering

Tags: .net, nosql, mapreduce, ravendb

Let's imagine I have a collection of documents called Users and I need to make several queries on it specifying diffent filtering clauses. I have two options here:

1. Create one common index and add filtering by Where clause for each
   query
2. Create several indexes, each of which will contain already
       filtered data

What are the rules to choose between these two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fewer and bigger indexes are better than higher number of smaller indexes